# subir projeto github

Tags: upload, github

alguém com paciencia o bastante para explicar como subir os arquivos para o github? já dei uma lida em alguns tutoriais, mas todos me retornam com erro na linha de comando

(Ubuntu 14.04)

Comment: Bem vindo, informe o comando utilizado, isso facilitar a ajuda.

Comment: Mostre os comandos que está tentando e o erro que está recebendo.

Comment: Não acho que essa pergunta seja a mesma da outra q foi posta como duplicata. A resposta é: use o comando `git push` com o terminal aberto na sua pasta. Caso prefira, use o GitHub Desktop, um APP pra desktop com o qual vc não precisa da linha de comando.